# How to save as a workbook that I already have, as a CSV, with a new name given by the user through an inputbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to save a workbook as a CSV file. The code I already have works well, but in addition, I want the user to be asked to type a new file (CSV) name, so that the new CSV file will be the one the user typed. How can I do that? So far I haven´t been able to do it. For now, what I need to do is to put the new name right in the code, and change it every time I want a different name. What code do I need to add?

I´ve tried to change "\Group 1" in the code, for CSV_FILE_NAME and it doesn't work.
Group 1 is a new CSV file, which is right in the code, and I don´t want that. I want the user to type any name.
CSV_FILE_NAME is the variable where the new name should be.

```
Sub CSV_TERMINADO()

    Range("A:D,F:F,H:H").Select
    Range("H1").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Nombre"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Correo"
    Range("A1").Select

    LibroActual = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    CSV_FILE_NAME = InputBox("Type a name", "CSV FILE")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Group 1", _
    FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & LibroActual

End Sub
```

I expect to end up with the new CSV file name typed by the user, not having to name it right in the code, before I run the macro (sub).

Comment: Use the InputBox function to obtain a name from the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & CSV_FILE_NAME _ ...
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21840695)

Comment: Please add an explenation of how this solves the problem

Comment: @s_t, wasn’t the question about how to use the value of  CSV_FILE_NAME variable in the SaveAs method?

Comment: @derHugo, the explanation, standing the question about how to use the value of CSV_FILE_NAME variable in the SaveAs method, is self evident

Comment: Maybe it could helps some lines of explaination, rather than a line of code, that's why I felt to mark your answer in this way. I'm not saying you gave the wrong answer, but maybe you can make it more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & CSV_FILE_NAME, _
                      FileFormat:=xlCSV
```